# Prove $\mathbb E(X∣Y)=0$ for $2$ variables

Tags: random

I was looking for an example of two dependent random variables in which
 $\mathbb E(X|Y)=\mathbb E(X)$

I found this example:
$X∼U[−1,1]$  and $Y=X^2$

---

How can I prove that $\mathbb E(X∣Y)=0$?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$E(XI_{{X^{2}} \leq x})=0$ for each $x$ because $X$ has same distribution as $-X$. This implies that $E(XI_A)=0$ for any $A \in \sigma (Y)$ and hence  $E(X|Y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! I can understand why in each symmetrical section the expectation of X is zero, but why E(X|Y)=0 also? Maybe I missed something..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$E(X|X^2) = E(-X|X^2) = -E(X|X^2)$

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful